# Tufte-book headers, TOC, title page behaving strangely

Tags: tufte

I did this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,toc,twoside]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}

\title{Manifesto of the Communist Party}
\author{K. Marx \& F. Engels}
\date{1888}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \include{intro.tex}
    \include{bourgeois_proletarians.tex}
    \include{proletarians_communists.tex}
    \include{socialist_communist_lit.tex}
    \include{oppo_parties.tex}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a PDF with the following issues:

- No title page or TOC, even though both options are in force
- Headers are behaving strangely, as illustrated in the attached image

The problems exist whether or not I use the `renewcommand`s.

Comment: You need `\maketitle` to generate the title, and `\tableofcontents` for the table of contents. There is no image in your question, so I don't know what's wrong with the headers.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I thought the package options replaced those commands. OK, so I added those, but now there's a new problem: there's a "Contents" header with no actual TOC, and the included chapters are no longer included.

Comment: PS. Can't upload the image for some reason.

Comment: So now we are back to the include problem from your other question. If the files aren't being included, then the log file shouldn't be very long. Please post it. Failing that, you can email it to me (follow the link in my profile to reach my homepage), and I will add the important parts to your question.